# How to check if there are rows and execute an Insert

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got the following SQL Code, I need

1. Execute an Insert only if the code returns more than 0 rows.
2. Put messages on the screen for the person who executes the script, saying
   No missing rows were detected or
   3 missing rows were detected and added.

   select * from DistributionKey_Section where SectionID 
   not in
   (
       select siteid from Site where SiteTypeCodeID IN(8)
   )
   and DistributionKeyID NOT IN
   (
       select DistributionKeyID from DistributionKey where UnitInclusive=1
   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
   @MissingRows int,
   @InsertedRows int    

SELECT *
FROM DistributionKey_Section
WHERE SectionID NOT IN ( select siteid from Site where SiteTypeCodeID IN(8) ) AND
      DistributionKeyID NOT IN ( SELECT DistributionKeyID FROM DistributionKey WHERE   
      UnitInclusive=1 )

SET @MissingRows = @@ROWCOUNT     

IF @MissingRows > 0
   BEGIN
   <Insert Statement/Logic>
   SET @InsertedRows = @@ROWCOUNT
   PRINT CAST(@InsertedRows as varchar(5)) + ' missing rows were detected and added'
   IF @MissingRows <> @InsertedRows 
      BEGIN
      RAISERROR('The number of rows inserted does not equal the number of rows missing', 16, 1)
      END
   END
ELSE
   PRINT 'No Missing Rows Detected'
```

Comment: This should get you pointed in the right direction.  I did not touch the insert as I was unsure of what exactly you wanted inserted and where.